# Unable to load dll when inheriting from a form

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, dll

I'm trying to create a new form (child form) that inherits from another form (parent form), and the problem is that, when I try to view the child form design view (in order to modify some controls), Visual Studio throws the following error: "Unable to load DLL 'fmodex': the specified module could not be found inherited form. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". The strange thing is that it actually works fine when I run the program, the error is only shown when I try to enter to the design view of the child form. I've checked the dll path and it's correct. Here's part of the the parent's code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        protected EventList eventList;
        protected FMOD.System system;
        protected int count;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a FMOD System object and initialize.
            FMOD.RESULT result;
            result = FMOD.Factory.System_Create(ref system);
            result = system.init(32, FMOD.INITFLAGS.NORMAL, (IntPtr)null); 

            //Event list
            eventList = new EventList(0,system);

            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And the child's code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows what could be happening? I can't understand why I can see the design view of the parent form and not the child form one.

Thanks in advance.